# Find and replace multiple characters in a string using VBA

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA, I need your help on the below scenario.

I have a Collection string which holds the value like below. so I need a VBA code replace the
single apostrophe(') with double apostrophe ('').

```
Value: 
Row1 - Jhon's Car
Row2 - Jhon's & Lucy's House
Row3 - Chrisman is playing
Row4 - Dina is dancing
```

The output I need like below:
Value:

```
Row1 - Jhon''s Car
Row2 - Jhon''s & Lucy''s House
Row3 - Chrisman is playing
Row4 - Dina is dancing
```

I did not tried. As am new to VBA i am not sure where to start

Comment: Please ensure the question tags are appropriate. VBA and VB.Net are not synonymous.

Comment: What application are you doing this in? Excel?

Answer (score 1):

In VBA it is the [replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function).
In VB .Net [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8.1) works.